# populate select options from form submit using getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have two forms on an html page and want to use the first form submit to select from database by php/mysql query and encode using JSON to populate the select options on my second form without leaving the page. The first form and php are sending the array but the second form is not being populated. Not sure what I am missing, any help is appreciated. See html, php and query below...

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="find.php" id="find" >
    <div class="input-box">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Select" />
    </div>
</form>
<div><h1>Checkin</h1></div>
<form method="post" action="checkin.php" id="contact-us">
<div id="contact-us-message"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" />
    <select id="clients" name="clients">
    </select>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$lastname = $_POST['lname'] ;
        $number = $_POST['phone'] ;
        $q = "select Site_ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Message,     ParentName from ClientInfo where LastName = '$lastname' and Phone = '$number'";
        $sql = mysql_query($q);
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
            $data[] = $row; 
        };
        echo json_encode($data);
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#find").submit(function(){
  $.getJSON('checkin.php',function(data){
    var items = '';
    $.each(data,function(name,value) {
        items += "<option type='text' value='"+value.Site_ID+"'>"+value.FirstName+" "+value.LastName+" </option>" ;
    });
    $("#clients").append(items);  
  });
});
</script>
```

---

EDIT

Ok I fixed the id issue and now when submitting it goes to php page and echos out the correct array. But it should not have left the html page. Anybody know why?

ARRAY

```
[{"Site_ID":"10000007","FirstName":"Drew","LastName"...}]
```

Comment: You script is totally unrelated to the HTML as it works only on an element with id "test" which does not exist in your HTML. Hm, maybe that's the whole problem?

Comment: start by inspecting AJAX requst in browser console to see what is being sent, and what is being returned...if anything. If you have 500 error there is a php code problem. These details need to be known in order to isolate problems to script or server code

Answer (score 1):

Your script works only on an element with `id="test"`, which does not exist in your HTML.

Comment: OP mentions 2 forms.. submit handler shows code to populate elements in form shown

Comment: One form is `#find` and the other one is `#contact-us`, none of them is `#test`.

Comment: ahhh   yup... I only noticed first form html..my bad

Answer (score 0):

According to me, try to attempt `Divide and Conquer` Rule, I mean divide each part of code and try to find out, each are working properly (independent code).

First thing about your `php` code

```
$lastname = $_POST['lname'] ;  // change to some value
$number = $_POST['phone'] ; // change to some value
$q = "select Site_ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Message,ParentName from ClientInfo where LastName = '".$lastname."' and Phone = '".$number."'";
$sql = mysql_query($q);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
$data[] = $row; 
};
echo json_encode($data);
```

First of all, do the proper `concatenation` of your query. And,then check, whether your current `php` code `encode` into `json` form properly or not ?

If you verified, above code, then move to your `javascript` code and check for all variable, which are related with `html` code. As you can see here

```
$("#test").submit(function(){
```

You have mentioned `test` id, but in your `html` code, it is nowhere exist.